# UICollectionView cannot find member

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to programmatically create a UICollectionView in Swift.
I can set it up, but as soon as I try to use more complex operations, such as insertItemsAtIndexPath oder deleteItemsAtIndexPath on my self.collectionView I get a "Cannot find member" error. Simpler operations, such as numberOfSections (as shown in my example code) work fine though. I have compared my code to  many others and can't find the problem.

**MainViewController**

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import MediaPlayer
import SpriteKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    var containerView : UIView?        
    var collectionView : UICollectionView?        

    var card : UIView?
    var fishArray = NSMutableArray()

    var cellCount = 20

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


        ////// COLLECTION VIEW

        var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappiDiTap:")

        var layout = FishFlowLayout()
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(96/2,352/2,1857/2,1117/2), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        collectionView!.registerClass(FishCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
        self.view.insertSubview(collectionView!, belowSubview:scaleBackground!)

        for i in 0..9 {
            fishArray.addObject("Fish: \(i)")
        }


    }


    func tappiDiTap(tapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if (tapGestureRecognizer.state == .Ended) {
            var initialPinchPoint : CGPoint = tapGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)
            var tappedCellPath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(initialPinchPoint)

            if (tappedCellPath==nil) {
                self.cellCount = self.cellCount+1
                self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            } else  {
                self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                println(slef.collectionView!.numberOfSections)
            }
        }
    }

    //////////////////COLLECTIONVIEW DELEGATE METHODS

    func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellCount
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FishCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

**Fish Flow Layout**

```
import UIKit

class FishFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    init() {
        super.init()

        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(220,270)
       self.minimumLineSpacing = 18
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
    }

}
```

**FishCollectionViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class FishCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        var card = Card(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(card)
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show where you are trying to make one of those calls and give us exactly what error you are getting?

Comment: I tried to implement deleteItemsAtIndexPath in the tapGestureRecognizer, so that when something's tapped something (or better the tapped cell) should go away.

Maybe some examplecode how to do deleteItemsAtPathIndex would help, or some more advanced implementation of UICollectionView in Swift would really help, since I'm not that experienced in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

The key to implementing `deleteItemsAtIndexPath` and `insertItemsAtIndexPath` is that you need to make sure that `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` returns the right number of items after the deletion or insertion. For example, if the table currently has 10 elements and you call `deleteItemsAtIndexPath` you need to make sure that the next time the collection view asks for the number of elements, it returns 9 or it will crash. The collection view does not handle increasing or decreasing that number for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is probably one of not unwrapping an optional value.

so for example trying to do this

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath])
    ...etc

}
```

will give you the error `could not find member 'insertItemsAtIndexPaths'`

which it can't. the method expects `[AnyObject]` not `[Optional]`

to fix unwrap the Optional.

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!])
        ...etc

    }
```